# Make responsive an image from another one

Tags: css, media-queries

I would like to center an arrow on a wheel.

The pointer should always point the little blank space between `100` and `30`.

I've started with this code:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    #pin {
        left: 46%;
        background: green;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:1100px) {
    #pin {
        left: 45%;
        background: blue;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:769px) {
    #pin {
        left: 44.7%;
        background: yellow;
    }
}
```

You could find a JS Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/jb386rfn/

The problem is I need to have a lot of CSS rules for each pixel.

It's very important as the pointer should point the right price.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could remove all of your media queries and simply use `#pin { left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); }` https://jsfiddle.net/psxzqwfj/

Comment: @Turnip, wow! It's working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: question is closed, but I already had the solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/pjon0L46/1/